# How to build the (activerecord) query in such one-many-many tables?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A `project` has many `tasks`.
A `task` can be handled by one of many `users`. For example:

```
Project    Task      By
-------  --------  ------
  P1        T1       U1
            T2       U2
  P2        T1       U3
            T2       U4
            T3       U5
  P3        T1       U1
            T2       U3
            T3       U5
  P4        T1       U1
            T2       U3
```

How can I query the `count of`, the ***last*** task in projects handled by users? The output report is expected as:

```
  Task   By   Count
  ----  ----  -----
   T2    U2     1
   T2    U3     1
   T3    U5     2
```

UPDATE: (for Deefours' comment): Here is what I did to get count of ***last*** task (but not sure how to get the **By** column):

```
self.find_by_sql('select task_id, count(task_id) as "count"
from (
        select task_id
        from (
                select * from tasks order by created_at desc
             )
        tasks_sorted 
        group by project_id
     )
latest_tasks 
group by task_id;')
```

Comment: Where might I find that? You haven't updated your Question. :)

Comment: I added some code to my answer that hope will help

Comment: Does a task has exactly one user (task belongs_to: :user)?

Comment: P1 and P2 both have a Task T1. This indicates a has_and_belongs_to_many realtionship. Is this correct?

Comment: @Meier, a task is handled by one user. Yes, P `has_and_belongs_to_many` T, and only the _last_ task in a project matters.

Comment: @Deefour, I added my solution as an answer. However, I am still looking for an `aciverecord` way, preferably nicer than plain SQL ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select task_id, user_id, count(user_id) as "count" from (
   select task_id, user_id from (
     select * from (
        select * from tasks order by tasks.created_at desc
     ) last_tasks group by project_id
   ) tasks_by_users INNER JOIN users ON tasks.task_id = tasks_users.task_id
 ) workload group by task_id, user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the query you are looking for:

```
SELECT t.task_id, u.user_id, count(*) as "count"
FROM project p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT project_id, MAX(created_at) as "created_at" FROM task GROUP BY project_id
) last_task ON p.project_id=last_task.project_id
INNER JOIN task t ON t.created_at=last_task.created_at
INNER JOIN users u ON t.user_id=u.user_id
GROUP BY t.task_id, u.user_id
```

Let me know if it didn't work as I'm unable to run it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try first doing a query to get the last task in every proyect to get a result set like this

```
P1    T2
P2    T3
P3    T3
```

Then left join the original table with the table resulting from this query by proyect and task filter the records where the Proyect in the subquery IS NOT NULL and get the count(*) group by subquery.task, originalTable.User

**Edit**

I'm assuming the number in in the column TASK is the order of the task in the proyect ( if you are storing this 'T1', 'T2'... values in the table you should consider change them for int values)

This query will get the last task for every project

```
SELECT project, 
'T' + CAST(MAX(CAST(REPLACE(task, 'T','') AS INT)) AS VARCHAR(3)) AS MaxTask
FROM Tasks
GROUP BY project
```

Then you have to join this table with the Tasktable again to get the user and group to get the count

```
SELECT mt.MaxTask, t.User, count(*) Count
FROM Tasks t LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT project, 
    'T' + CAST(MAX(CAST(REPLACE(task, 'T','') AS INT)) AS VARCHAR(3)) AS MaxTask
    FROM Tasks
    GROUP BY project
) AS mt ON t.project = mt.project AND t.task = mt.task
WHERE mt.task IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY mt.MaxTask, t.User
```

Answer (score 0):

use below query :

```
SELECT P.task_id, P.user_id, count(*) as "count"
FROM project p
INNER JOIN task t ON t.task_id = p.task_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT project_id, MAX(created_at) FROM task GROUP BY project_id) l 
            ON  l.project_id = p.project_id
            AND l.created_at = t.created_at
GROUP BY P.task_id, P.user_id
```